# Index a character in a wchar_t array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, unicode, wchar-t

The thread "[Size of wchar_t* for surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503931/size-of-wchar-t-for-surrogate-pair-unicode-character-out-of-bmp-on-windows)" shows, that the size of memory required to save a wchar_t value may differ as it can take more space to encode some characters (surrogate pair). That leads me to the following question: How do I then navigate along an array of wchar_t values? Because I can now not just increment or decrement the current address by a fixed size of wchar_t.

CORRECTION: By "How do I then navigate along an array of wchar_t values" I meant how you navigate between the code points which may represented by a variable number of wchar_t values.

Comment: Sorry: is this C or C++ ?

Comment: @Sam I think you need to go back and reread the answers to that question.  The point was that `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*` are different sizes.  The size required to store a `wchar_t` will be consistent within your program.

Comment: Perhaps you misread the question you linked; that is only talking about `sizeof(wchar_t)` and `sizeof(wchar_t *)`. It does not talk about how many characters are used to encode surrogate pairs (the OP thought it did but he was mistaken).  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I think the question is for example the [Han character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2008a/index.htm) which is using 2 wchar_t characters. So `ptr++` and `ptr--` do not work here, as it only moves 1 wchar_t. How to navigate instead?

Comment: Wimmel nailed it. Exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of `wchar_t` may be different in various different systems, **but** it's certain and fixed during run-time or compile-time on a machine.

You can retrieve its size by operator `sizeof` and also you can iterate over it as same as other types.

The type `wchar_t` based on a specific locale has a maximum size to store a character. So, the mapping between string's code-units to the text's characters is *one-to-one*, therefore don't worry about iterating over characters of a wide string as same as other types to read next or previous character. (Unlike Unicode)

However, this is the only bright part of `wchar_t` strings. Using them as a general way to store any arbitrary string is not easy task. So, you should use Unicode aware things. A related Q&A is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11107608/952747).

Comment: I think the answer of M M was helpful to me. Yes, my question may not be so clear at all as the entire thing about encodings is quiet confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `wchar_t` to perform manipulations on Unicode strings. Seriously, just don't. As you've already observed, there isn't a one-to-one correspondence between `wchar_t` objects and Unicode code points. Use a library such as ICU to manipulate Unicode text.

Comment: +1 for providing practical advice to a situation that is difficult to get right on your own

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues here and using a library such as ICU will help you avoid a lot of problems. The issue with surrogate characters in UTF-16 is not the only problem if you are trying to count "characters".

If you just have to walk a wchar_t string the values for surrogate values are uniquely defined as a leading value (0xd800 to 0xdbff) followed by a trailing value (0xdc00 to 0xdfff). You can use this knowledge to walk forward or backward through an array counting the "characters". This assumes you have a valid set of values.

Another issue is values in the stream that aren't a character by themselves. For example U+0301 is COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT with adds an accent to the previous value. These can be an issue whether using UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is clarifying the nature of the `wchar_t` as a type. That seemed to to have been misunderstood before the question had the "CORRECTION" added.

As with any concrete type, `sizeof(wchar_t)` is constant for a particular system as is `sizeof(wchar_t *)`.

In language terms you can can navigate an array of `wchar_t` just the same as you can navigate an array of any other type.

However, working with text characters encoded with varying numbers of `wchar_t`s is another and much more complex matter. The other answers have to some extent addressed that.

Comment: You are right. I did correct my question which was mistakable.

Comment: I'm not sure why I have been getting down votes here. I've attempted to clarify my answer. I would appreciate any feedback as to why this answer is deserving of down votes?

Comment: I have also no idea why someone did down vote your answer. I gave you an up vote to neutralize the down vote =).